# gmail app password for outlook2007

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

The article at https://www.msoutlook.info/question/902 lets me believe that I can continue using outlook 2007 for my gmail if I get an app password. But google says that it’s not available for my acct. How to make it available?

Comment: Do you have 2fa enabled for your Gmail account? See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: yes, when i was trying this i had 2fa enabled. have since turned it off. google of course does not give a reason why the app pswrd is not available.

Comment: 2fa needs to be set up to create an app password. Also, per the article, is your account 1) a school or work account, or 2) do you have Advanced Protection turned on?

Comment: 2fa was on. it's not a school or work acct. i don't know what's "advanced protection." i'm sure i don't need it. but g would like me to do some security review...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a app password for your Gmail account as mentioned in the below article?

[Create & use App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en#:%7E:text=Create%20%26%20use%20App%20Passwords)

And agree with 2br-2b: **App Passwords can only be used with accounts that have 2-Step Verification turned on**.

If you try a lot and end up unable to create an app password, the problem may be related to your Gmail account, it's suggested that you could contact the support of Gmail.

On the other hand, due to [the security updates and technical support of Office 2007 are not available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/end-of-support-for-office-2007-942272d3-bd72-4944-9f82-02ed307cf934?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), it's suggested to upgrade to the later Office(such as office 2019 or Microsoft 365) to get a better user experience.

Comment: my question is just about why g does not let me create an app password. i tried using ol2019, but 2fa-acct creation on it fails - it does not send mails. and i have a custom form on ol2007  that does not work on ol2019.

Comment: how to contact g support? not obvious on their pages...

Comment: ok. now i was able to create an app password. as g gives no feedback, i don't know why it didn't work at the 1st try. did the security checks that they requested, and deleted some files from their cloud that was almost full.